# jquery serializeArray() equivalent object

Tags: javascript, jquery, serializearray

```
var url="service/signProcess.aspx";

//sets the important hidden field of the form by which server decides what to send

$('#hdnReqType2').val('sign87162');

var data=$("#frmLogin").serializeArray();
var success=function(rdata, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(rdata);
         };

var fail=function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log("Error" + errorThrown + "  " + textStatus);
     }
$.post(url,data,success,"text").fail(fail);
```

I am using this in the console of the page 'http://fsa.citop.in/lnct/' opened in chrome(when login form of the page is empty) and got a JSON String as response.

I found out at https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ that serializeArray() returns an array of objects having name and value.
so when I used

```
var data=[{name :"txtLogId",value: ""},{name:"txtLogPass",value: ""},{name:"hdnReqType2",value: "sign87162"}];
```

which I thought to be equivalent object to object returned by $("#frmLogin").serializeArray() . Server gave me a HTML page in response.

I tried console.log(data) with both the version of data variable and couldn't find any difference. Please explain me whats the difference between both the version of data and what could be the correct equivalent object to serailizeArray().

Comment: with which data did you compare the result of **$('#frmLogin').serializeArray()**

Comment: when did you make a **request** to server to get an **response**.

Comment: I compared $('#frmLogin').serializeArray() with [{name :"txtLogId",value: ""},{name:"txtLogPass",value: ""},{name:"hdnReqType2",value: "sign87162"}].

Comment: last line of the code $.post(url,data,success,"text").fail(fail); , I believe to be a post request

Comment: the **data** in **success** callback function is the response object **(JSON)**.  You can use any other name than **data**, and you will get it.

Comment: yeah. sorry for that. but I was talking about the data which is being send in the request. now I have corrected my question again.

Answer (score 0):

The **data** argument in **success** callback is the response object **(JSON)**.
Your **data** variable before **success** function is conflicting with **data** argument in **success** callback. 
I suggest you change the name of the **data** variable or change the name of **data** argument in **success** function.

```
var url="service/signProcess.aspx";

//sets the important hidden field of the form by which server decides what to send

$('#hdnReqType2').val('sign87162');

var data=$("#frmLogin").serializeArray();
var success=function(dat_a, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(dat_a);
};

var fail=function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log("Error" + errorThrown + "  " + textStatus);
};
$.post(url,data,success,"text").fail(fail);
```

Here in the above code I have changed **data** argument in **success callback function** to **dat_a**.

Comment: yeah. sorry for that. but I was talking about the data which is being send in the request. now I have corrected my question again.